# Create Double Array from equal elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new at Javascript. I want to create of 2D array from equal elements (elements are objects). For instance,

```
oldArray = [a,b,c,d,e,f]  (a=b=f, d=e)
```

Lets say object `a` is equal to object `b` and object `f`. Then object `d` is equal to object `e`. So the new Array should be

```
newArray = [[a,b,f],[c],[d,e]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since we are talking about objects, do you mean that those objects points to the same **reference** or do they own the same **keys and values**, meaning that they have equal properties and values but not the same reference? It's a subtle difference, but nonetheless **very** important.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `groupBy` function using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The `groupBy` function accepts a predicate, so you can define the grouping property/value. The result of the grouping is an object where each property is a group of items (array). Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to extract to an array of arrays.

```js
const groupBy = (predicate, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((r, o) => ({
    ...r,
    [predicate(o)]: [...r[predicate(o)] || [], o]
  }), {});
  
const data = [{ id: 'a', val: 1 }, { id: 'b', val: 1 }, { id: 'c', val: 2 }, { id: 'd', val: 3 }, { id: 'e', val: 3 }, { id: 'f', val: 1 }];

const result = Object.values(groupBy(({ val}) => val, data));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

- Create a `temp` array which contains objects with properties

  - obj - reference of the object
  - index - index of object in the resulting array
- Iterate over the `oldArray` and for each object in it check whether it exists in `temp` array.

  - If it does not exist, add an entry for it in `temp` array and also add it to the result array.
  - Else update the existing sub-array in result array.

```js
let a = {x:1}, c = {y:2}, d = {z:3};
let b = a, f = a, e = d;
let oldArray = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
let result = [];
let temp = [];
oldArray.forEach(c => {
  let item = temp.find(o => o.obj === c);
  if(item) result[item.index].push(c);
  else {
    temp.push({obj:c,index:result.length});
    result.push([c]);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```